# How to configure ports on Vagrant and ruby-debug-ide

Tags: ruby, vagrant, ruby-debug-ide

I’m trying to configure debugger for my web application, but I run into trouble with specifying correct ports for it.
Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.68.8"
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
```

/etc/hosts (on my host machine)

```
192.168.68.8    mysite.com
```

I installed  these two gems for debugging

```
gem 'ruby-debug-ide', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'debase', group: [:development,:test]
```

I read that in order to use ruby-debug-ide on vagrant, I should run 
`rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80  --dispatcher-port 8080 -- bin/rails s`
where `--port` should be guest port from Vagrantfile and host port for `--dispatcher-port``

But it says

```
Permission denied - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 80
```

On the other side, if I try to change those ports in Vagrantfile, I lose the opportunity to reach my application from 127.0.0.1:specified_port, but still can do it from mysite.com, which is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already have something listening on port 80 (apache or nginx) so you cant bind on this port. You can do one of the following

1. start rails on another port like 3000

in your vagrant start `rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000  --dispatcher-port 3000 -- bin/rails s`

If you use a private network IP in your vagrantfile you dont need to forward port as you'll access your VM server using its own IP

2. check what is listening on port 80

run `sudo netstat -nltp` in your VM, check the process which binds the port 80 and kill it

For example

```
vagrant@precise32:/etc/init.d$ sudo netstat -nltp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      512/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1827/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      652/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58397           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      539/rpc.statd
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      512/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      652/sshd
...
```

so you'll kill the apache2 process (PID 1827)